# AutoComplete on focus show default drop down doesn't seem to work

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I want to use the autocomplete menu for a textbox, but instead of having to type something before you get results, i want the menu to pop up with all available options first on focus, then narrow as you type.

The problem is i tried the focus but with no success:

here is my code:

```
 var neighborhood_name = ["LA","NW","SE","GF"];
var statuses = [];


$(document).ready(function() {
    BindControls();
});

function BindControls() {

    $('#services').autocomplete({
        source: neighborhood_name,
        minLength: 0,
        scroll: true
    }).focus(function() {
        $(this).autocomplete("search", "");
    });
}
```

I'm using the follwing jQuery

https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css

https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js

https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js

https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.2/jquery-ui.js

Whenever I click on my input i get the following error: $(...).autocomplete is not a function on focus, althought it works when I start typing something but not when I want to see the full list. \

Any clues?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you to have included Jquery UI library.

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/jquery-ui.js" ></script>
```

So you will include both Jquery and Jquery UI.

[Edit]

Here is working Code

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-3.0.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.min.js" ></script>

<input type="text" id="services" value="" />
<script>
 var neighborhood_name = ["LA","NW","SE","GF"];
var statuses = [];


$(document).ready(function() {
    BindControls();
});

function BindControls() {

    $('#services').autocomplete({
        source: neighborhood_name,
        minLength: 0,
        scroll: true
    }).focus(function() {
        $(this).autocomplete("search", "");
    });
} 

</script>
```

Comment: I have already included that sorry, 

here is what I have so far: 

<link href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.2/jquery-ui.js" ></script>

Comment: Please see above working code. No need to include multiple jqueryUIs.